# Vagrant setup for nginx load balancing with a php site

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, vagrantfile

I've looked up a few topics on here around this, but none of the solutions I've found so far seem to work.

I have 3 boxes created via a Vagrantfile with puppet modules, which have nginx and php installed. I've created a simple webpage to output the host name statically, plus php info.

On the load balancer I have the following code for /etc/nginx/sites-available/127.0.0.1 (note this is now the default site and linked setup through my Vagrantfile)

```
# vagrant/puppet/modules/nginx/files/loadBalancer/127.0.0.1
upstream backend {
  server 192.168.205.20; #ip of second machine
  server 192.168.205.30; #ip of third machine
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www/app;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

The two additional hosts which host this web app, have the following file for their /etc/nginx/sites-available/127.0.0.1

```
# vagrant/puppet/modules/nginx/files/127.0.0.1
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www/app;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    proxy_pass  http://backend;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

However, this results in only one page coming up (the load balancers, it never alternates to the other two like it should).

I have also tried passing in the backend upstream as the fastcgi_pass but this causes a 502 bad gateway. Is there something I am misunderstanding as far how this should function? Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: hi, why do you have the location/handler for php files on the load balancer, wouldn't it take effect that it picks the url and does not forward ? can you try remove it, it should then pass to the backend and defined in the location above

Comment: Apologies, not sure I follow, so remove the location block from the loadbalancer? Isn't the load balancer meant to have that as well as the usptream block though?

Comment: Okay, never mind I understand what you meant now, and it works as expected. Thanks for that!